# 自分になりたい。 自分でありたい。 What's the difference?

Tags: grammar, nuances, verbs, particle-に, particle-で

I know both sentences more or less mean "I want to be myself", but I'm not sure of the subtle differences.

When would you use でありたい over になりたい ?

Source: Tsurune season 2 trailer. Both are said one after the other at the end of the trailer.
Why does the main character in this trailer say one after the other?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Xになりたい suggests that the subject is not yet X while Xでありたい does not have this implication (much).

So 自分になりたい sounds like *the subject is trying to be the true self* and 自分でありたい like *the subject wants to stay (to be) the true self*.